# Why a user with sysadmin permissions can't access msdb as an EXECUTE AS user?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a `testuser` login set as `sysdamin`, and used it for the clause `execute as` in the following function created in a test database other than the `msdb`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyTestFunction] 
    (@job_name SYSNAME)
RETURNS INT
WITH EXECUTE AS 'TestUser'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT 

    SELECT TOP 1 @id = schedule_id 
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules

    RETURN @id
END
```

When I execute `MyTestFunction` I get the following error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobschedules', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

In change, if I directly log in with the `TestUser` login and straight execute the `SELECT` statement using the test database, it works fine.

User `TestUser` can directly access `msdb` from the test database, but can't access `msdb` if used in the `execute as` clause of a function of the test database.

How can I access the `msdb` database from a function created in another database?

Comment: The `EXECUTE AS` impersonated context is sandboxed to the current database (unless the database is `TRUSTWORTHY`). Consider [module signing](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) to elevate permissions for a specific stored proc.

Comment: Dan, please, could you provide some link to some documentation?

Comment: Here's the documentation link for [`ADD SIGNATURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql). I added an answer with a worked example gleaned from the referenced module signing article.

Answer (score 0):

The `EXECUTE AS` impersonated security context is sandboxed to the current database. You cannot access other databases within the function unless the database is `TRUSTWORTHY`, which is not generally a good practice.

For cross-database access by minimally privileged users, consider using [module signing](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#crossdbcert). This allows you to grant access to other databases and objects within the module execution context without granting the end user direct permissions. Users only need permissions on the function.

Below is an example script gleaned from the referenced article for your particular need. Although this basic technique could be extended to provide `sysadmin` permissions, the best practice is to use a minimally privileged account.

```
-- Create a certificate in msdb
USE msdb;
CREATE CERTIFICATE msdb_certificate
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'p@Ss0RDforTheceRT1cate'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'For cross-database access to msdb database';

-- create a user from certification with needed permissions
CREATE USER msdb_certificate_user FROM CERTIFICATE msdb_certificate;
GRANT SELECT ON msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules TO msdb_certificate_user;

-- Copy certificate to user database (Example)
DECLARE @cert_id int = cert_id('msdb_certificate');
DECLARE @public_key  varbinary(MAX) = certencoded(@cert_id),
        @private_key varbinary(MAX) =
           certprivatekey(@cert_id,
              'p@Ss0RDforTheceRT1cate',
              'p@Ss0RDforTheceRT1cate');
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
      'CREATE CERTIFICATE msdb_certificate
       FROM  BINARY = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @public_key, 1) + '
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' +
          convert(varchar(MAX), @private_key, 1) + ',
          DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''p@Ss0RDforTheceRT1cate'',
          ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''p@Ss0RDforTheceRT1cate'')';
EXEC YourDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
ALTER CERTIFICATE msdb_certificate REMOVE PRIVATE KEY; --remove ephemeral private key
GO

--sign module with certificate 
USE YourDatabase;
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.MyTestFunction BY CERTIFICATE msdb_certificate
   WITH PASSWORD = 'p@Ss0RDforTheceRT1cate';
ALTER CERTIFICATE msdb_certificate REMOVE PRIVATE KEY; --remove ephemeral private key
GO
--users only need permissions on directly invoked module
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.MyTestFunction TO YourUser;
GO
```